# Obversing route change to apply equivalent to onload

Tags: ember.js, routes, observers

I'm trying to observe the route change to apply some common action once rendered. The idea is to have a feature similar to the `onload` but as we use a single-page app this needs to be triggered on each route changes. (could be scoped to the new view)

I found how to observe the currentPath changes:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentPathDidChange: function() {
    prettyPrint()
  }.observes('currentPath');
});
```

While this works good in some cases, it gets triggered when the route changes, but still to early to apply content changes as it seem to append before the content gets rendered.

Any idea on the best practice to achieve such goal?

Comment: I left an answer, but I would suggest that in many cases, it's actually an anti-pattern if you have to wait for the views in order to muck with the DOM. Perhaps there's a better place to put whatever DOM manipulation you're doing, like some view's `didInsertElement`?

Comment: If you implement the views, you can do that in [`didInsertElement`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried deferring the code with [`Ember.run.schedule`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_schedule)? For instance,

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentPathDidChange: function() {
    Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function() {
      prettyPrint();
    });
  }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the [deprecation of Controllers in Ember 1.x](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/) finding the url in the router would be a good way to future proof your apps. You can do this in `ember-cli` like so:

```
// similar to onLoad event behavior
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function (model){
    Ember.run.next(() => {
      console.log(this.get('router.url'));
    });
  }
});

// hacky way to get current url on each transition
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    didTransition: function() {
      Ember.run.next(() => {
        console.log(this.get('router.url'));
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This will log: `/posts` and `/posts/3/comments` ect.

Comment: The deprecation page doesn't mention that controllers are being deprecated. Just `ArrayControllers` and `ObjectControllers`, but not all controllers.

Comment: That's true, but I think eventually this logic should end up in either a routable-component or a route.  You can currently (1.13.6) use a `Controller` without any deprecation warnings, however I think that may change in Ember 2 (currently in beta).